# How to send data to Android Wear TileService

Tags: java, android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0, wear-os-tiles

I don't really know, how to feed my Wear OS tiles with data. Currently, I am experimenting with receiving my heart rate from a BroadcastReceiver, which works but my value is always 0 inside onTileRequest.

This is my TileService...

```java
public class HeartRateTileService extends TileService {
    private static final String RESOURCES_VERSION = "1";

    private String currentHeartrate = "0";

    @Override          //onStartCommand never gets called
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        int i = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Log.d("HeartRate", "onStartCommand " + currentHeartrate);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(messageReceiver, new IntentFilter("heart-rate-to-activity"));
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(messageReceiver, new IntentFilter("heart-rate-to-activity"));
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected ListenableFuture<TileBuilders.Tile> onTileRequest(
            @NonNull RequestBuilders.TileRequest requestParams
    ) {
        Log.d("HeartRate", "onTileRequest " + currentHeartrate);
        return Futures.immediateFuture(new TileBuilders.Tile.Builder()
                .setResourcesVersion(RESOURCES_VERSION)
                .setFreshnessIntervalMillis(1000*60)
                .setTimeline(new TimelineBuilders.Timeline.Builder()
                        .addTimelineEntry(new TimelineBuilders.TimelineEntry.Builder()
                                .setLayout(new LayoutElementBuilders.Layout.Builder()
                                        .setRoot(
                                                layout()
                                        ).build()
                                ).build()
                        ).build()
                ).build()
        );
    }

    private LayoutElementBuilders.LayoutElement layout() {
        return new LayoutElementBuilders.Row.Builder()
                .setWidth(wrap())
                .setHeight(expand())
                .setVerticalAlignment(LayoutElementBuilders.VERTICAL_ALIGN_CENTER)
                .addContent(new LayoutElementBuilders.Text.Builder()
                        .setText(currentHeartrate)
                        .build()
                ).build();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected ListenableFuture<ResourceBuilders.Resources> onResourcesRequest(
            @NonNull RequestBuilders.ResourcesRequest requestParams
    ) {
        Log.d("HeartRate", "onResourcesRequest " + currentHeartrate);
        return Futures.immediateFuture(new ResourceBuilders.Resources.Builder()
                .setVersion(RESOURCES_VERSION)
                .build()
        );
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver messageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("HeartRate", "message: " + currentHeartrate);
            currentHeartrate = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
        }
    };

}
```

This is what I get...
As you see onTileRequest is always 0. Maybe it's because onCreate gets called too whenever onTileRequest gets called and therefore my data is 0 at this moment. But how can I save the heart rate permanently then? Am I doing something wrong? Or are tiles just not meant to receive data of a BroadcastReceiver. Are there other ways? I literally found nothing about updating tiles with data on the internet.

```
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
D/HeartRate: onCreate 0
W/t.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
D/HeartRate: onTileRequest 0
D/HeartRate: onResourcesRequest 0
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: changeCanvasOpacity: opaque=false
D/HeartRate: onCreate 0
D/HeartRate: message: 0
D/HeartRate: message: 0
D/HeartRate: message: 81
D/HeartRate: message: 81
D/HeartRate: onCreate 0
D/HeartRate: message: 81
    message: 81
    message: 0
D/HeartRate: message: 81
I/chatty: uid=10096(com.pezcraft.myapplication) identical 1 line
D/HeartRate: message: 82
D/HeartRate: message: 72
I/chatty: uid=10096(com.pezcraft.myapplication) identical 1 line
D/HeartRate: message: 72
D/HeartRate: message: 73
I/chatty: uid=10096(com.pezcraft.myapplication) identical 1 line
D/HeartRate: message: 73
D/HeartRate: onCreate 0
D/HeartRate: onTileRequest 0
D/HeartRate: message: 75
I/chatty: uid=10096(com.pezcraft.myapplication) identical 1 line
D/HeartRate: message: 75
    message: 0
D/HeartRate: message: 75
I/chatty: uid=10096(com.pezcraft.myapplication) identical 2 lines
D/HeartRate: message: 75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifecycle of the TileService isn't the same as your application. Your tile service might be destroyed and a new one created for additional requests. It's probably unlikely that the service created to produce a tile, was awake when the heartbeat sensor data was received.

This thread on Android Widgets https://twitter.com/marxallski/status/1454889465206513667 also applies to Wear Tiles and Complications.

> Ideally data is cached in memory, if not, use a worker to refresh it and whenever data is cached it should notify the widget to update.

> You should not keep data inside the GlanceAppWidget, it should be kept at the application scope

The same applies here.

Your tile should execute very quickly, effectively statelessly

- not initiating a potentially long or failing network request, or subscribing to background data
- returning data cached in memory (application scope) or read from a DB (Room?)

Try subscribing to the data outside the tile. Store the data tied to the application (a field in your Application subclass), use DI like Koin/Hilt, or store in a database that you can read out of when you get the onTileRequest request.

I'm not very familiar with Health data or Broadcasts - but this seems relevant https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/health-services/passive